# How can I dock a combobox inside labelframe1 that is already inside a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter

I have a LabelFrame inside a class. The LabelFrame is anchored in the class, inside def __init __, via "self". Inside the LabelFrame there are various widgets, but anchored only to "self".

I would like to anchor the widgets inside the LabelFrame, so that when I move the position of the LabelFrame I don't have to move each widget individually yet.

How can I dock the combobox inside labelframe1? (always remaining inside the page with the class?). So that by moving the position of the LabelFrame I still don't have to move each widget individually

```
root = tk.Toplevel()
root.geometry("1200x1000")
root.state("normal")

     class Page (tk.Frame):
         def __init __ (self, master, ** kw):
             super () .__ init __ (master, ** kw)
    
             #labelframe anchored to "self"
             labelframe1 = LabelFrame (self, text = "Label Frame", width = 600, height = 190, bg = "white", foreground = 'black')
             labelframe1.place (x = 10, y = 13)
    
             #combobox anchored to "self"
             asas = Label (self, text = "Name", bg = "black", foreground = 'black', background = 'white', font = 'TkDefaultFont 11')
             asas.place (x = 17, y = 37)
             Name = Entry (self, width = 5)
             Name.place (x = 522, y = 36)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to put all objects (self.asas, self.Name, self.combo) into `self.labelframe1' and define width and height with self.labelframe.place( x, y, width, height).

Comment: @Derek Interesting. Can you show me better in an answer based on my code please? Thank you

Comment: Here is an example. try quitting the code and from shell enter the following snippet.     `A.labelframe1.place(x = 120, y = 120, width = 400, height = 150)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code with a few modifications that place all objects inside labelframe1.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)

        # labelframe anchored to "self.labelframe1"
        self.labelframe1 = tk.LabelFrame(
            self, text = "Label Frame", foreground = 'black')
        self.labelframe1.place(x = 10, y = 13, width = 600, height = 400)

        # combobox anchored to "self.labelframe1"
        self.asas = tk.Label(
            self.labelframe1, text = "Name", background = 'black',
            foreground = 'white', font = 'TkDefaultFont 11')
        self.asas.place(x = 17, y = 36, width = 100, height = 30)

        self.Name = tk.Entry(self.labelframe1, width = 10)
        self.Name.place(x = 122, y = 36)
        # manage the Frame
        self.place(x = 0, y = 0, width = 700, height = 500)

A = Page(root)

# Insert any tkinter widget except(Tk|Toplevel)
A.combo = ttk.Combobox(A.labelframe1, width = 27)
A.combo.place(x = 200, y = 36)

root.geometry('620x425')
root.mainloop()
```

You can now change `labelframe1.place()` and objects inside it will move with it.

Comment: Thank you. How come if I replace y = 13 with y = 113 (to try to lower the position of the labelframe a little), the lower horizontal border of the labelframe disappears? I wanted to place the labelframe a little lower, but the bottom horizontal border of the labelframe disappears. Why? How to solve?

Comment: The place manager can position objects outside the visible GUI and that's what you are doing. Objects inside LabelFrames or other containers can also be positioned outside visible scope. Solution is to increase size of `Tk` or `Toplevel` window or reduce LabelFrame width or height.

Comment: I know, but the problem is strange, because replacing y = 13 with y = 113, the labelframe1 always stays in the GUI. So I don't understand why the lower horizontal border of labelframe1 disappears. Out of curiosity, try yourself replacing y = 13 with y = 113

Comment: The place coordinate system is referenced to top left corner of container as 0,0 so increasing 'y' will push it down the page and eventually out of the visible scope.

Comment: Yes, I know that, i'm saying something else. By setting the label frame as (x = 10, y = 113), the label frame is positioned slightly lower on the screen but is still visible in the GUI. The problem is not that the labelframe goes out of the visible range because with (x = 10, y = 113) it lowers only slightly, while remaining visible in the GUI. The problem is that the lower horizontal border of the labelframe disappears, but the labelframe is still visible in the GUI. There is something wrong, and it is positioned at a medium-down height, so its lower edge disappears for strange reasons

Comment: Look screenshot https://ibb.co/xjhbGKK

Comment: Yes I see the problem. It has to do with the frame size `self.place(x = 0, y = 0, width = 700, height = 500)`. This cuts off at 500. Solution: increase self (frame) height.

Comment: Thank you. Now is all ok